# Optimize SQL query when GROUP BY and ORDER BY expressions are different?

Tags: sql, optimization, query-optimization

From the Order By Optimization in Mysql documentation, I quote...

> In some cases, MySQL cannot use
>   indexes to resolve the ORDER BY,
>   although it still uses indexes to find
>   the rows that match the WHERE clause.
>   These cases include the following:
>
> - You have different ORDER BY and GROUP BY expressions.

Is there any darn workaround for this?

My query is...

```
SELECT *
FROM (`product`)
WHERE `Category1` = 'PC'
AND `Category2` = 'desktop'
GROUP BY `product_code`
ORDER BY `reviews` desc, `popularity` desc
LIMIT 10
```

Explain output...

```
select_type: SIMPLE
table: product
type: ref
possible_keys: Category1_idx
key: Category1_idx
key_len: 390
ref: const, const
rows: 508
Extra: Using where; Using temporary
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GROUP BY is normally used with functions like SUM() to aggregate records. Your query doesn't seem to require the group by clause as such. Would the following work better?

SELECT *
FROM (`product`)
WHERE `Category1` = 'PC'
AND `Category2` = 'desktop'
ORDER BY `product_code`, `reviews` desc, `popularity` desc
LIMIT 10

You would create an index to match of course.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: I need the GROUP BY to ease up some of programming operations. Is there any other way apart from removing the GROUP BY - may be some sub-querying or something?

Comment: Have you checked the records that your existing query is returning, if you group without aggregating, sometimes the results can be unexpected.